# Object reference not set to an instance of an object for label

Tags: c#, gridview, nullreferenceexception

I am trying to set label text which resides in `gridview` on `RowDataBound` event of `gridview`.The code for the same is as follows:

```
protected void GridView2_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        int day = Convert.ToInt32(DropDownList3.SelectedValue);
        int days = System.DateTime.DaysInMonth(2013,day);
        Label lab = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("d");
        lab.Text = days.ToString();
    }
}
```

GRIDVIEW STRUCTURE:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" OnRowDataBound="GridView2_RowDataBound" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="name" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="n" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="dept" HeaderText="Department" SortExpression="d" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="code" HeaderText="Employee Code" SortExpression="c" />
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Total days" >
                <itemtemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="d" runat="server" Text="" />
                </itemtemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                </asp:GridView>
```

In the above code,'d' is the id of the label in the gridview.On the highlighted line i am getting error that `OBJECT REFERENCE NOT SET TO INSTANCE OF AN OBJECT.`As far as I understand, the new label is not being created.Then how to assign values calculated in this event to gridview's label?

Comment: Debug your code and check what you get with e.Row.FindControl("d")
I guess that this is null.

Comment: Almost all cases of `NullReferenceException` are the same. Please see "[What is a NullReferenceException in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net)" for some hints.

Comment: i know that it is null,but i dont know the way to solve it...can you please suggest me.

Comment: The documentation explains that the [`FindControl` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/486wc64h.aspx) will return `null` if the specified control does not exist.

Comment: show the gridview markup

Comment: Please update your post and do not put the code in a comment

Comment: i just want that calculated value of 'days' should be displayed in gridview,thats it..for that i am trying to assign days to label and that label to 'd' that is label in gridview...

Comment: @tomtom...sorry...i am newbie,will take care now onwards.....please have a look at updated question.

Answer (score 1):

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" OnRowDataBound="GridView2_RowDataBound">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="n" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="Department" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Seats" HeaderText="Employee Code" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Total days">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="d" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

where is your columns tag, put in the columns tag and try

Comment: still not working.Issue is as it is....can you suggest me any other way round to display days values in the gridview...?

Comment: i marked it as answer,but not able to upvote as i am new to stackoverflow.It requires 15 reputation for that.thanks once again.